# Assigning number of rows of one table to column of another

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

My situation: I have one table called 'staff', which contains various members. Beside this I have another table called 'children', which contains the children of the members (with foreign key 'staff_id').

Now: How can I add a column called 'number_of_children' to my staff table, which contains the number of entries in 'children' table where the 'staff_id' is my staffid?

Additional: In children table i have a column 'consider'. I only want to consider the entries where consider is set to true. Is there a way to include this to the model's function, too? Would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Please put your code what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a relation between Staff and Children

```
class Staff extends Model
{
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Children::class);
    }
}
```

Then, you can query the children like this

```
$numberOfChildren = $staffMember->children()->count();
```

[More information here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Thanks for the beatiful solution! I extended the question above, may you can answer the additional question, too?

Comment: That's a simple where condition on the query of childrens. `$numberOfChildren = $staffMember->children()->where('consider', true)->count()`

Comment: oh right, used this a couple of times.. Today is not my day.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why have a dedicated column for this and not just calculate it dynamically? This way you don't ever need to worry about updating it each time etc.

On your `staff` model, just add a `hasMany()` relationship for the `children` model.

```
//Staff Model
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Children'); //Substitute Children for the actual name of the model
}
```

Then you can just get the children whenever you need with `$staff->children->count()`.

Comment: Thanks for the beatiful solution! I extended the question above, may you can answer the additional question, too?